# Possible of override 2 zones with one thermostat

Tags: wiring, thermostat

I have a vacation home with 2 zone heating.  In the winter, it would be nice to be able to have remote access to the thermostat and 'turn on the heat'.  Normally when vacant the 2 zones will be set to 52 degrees and it is 2 wire.  I was thinking of installing a 3rd thermostat wire (with C wire) and one of the new thermostat ecobee/nest/etc that I could access remotely.

However, is there a way to wire this to essentially 'override' the 2 existing (manual) thermostats so that when we get there we can manually use the 2 zones separately.  I'm just trying to avoid an additional $250 and the next to impossible addition of a C wire to the existing thermostats.

thanks

Comment: Can you post a diagram of your setup?

Comment: Are the 2 zones for 1st and 2nd floors? If the goal is heating up the house before you get there, just install the remote tstat  on the 1st floor.